# How to confirm that a string is valid base36 of an integer?

Tags: php, base36

I had code like this:

```
$alias = 'myalias';
echo "<pre>";
echo "
ALIAS: $alias
ROUND: ", intval($alias, 36) , "\n" ,
"AGAIN: ", base_convert(intval($alias, 36), 10, 36)
;

echo "<hr>";

$alias = '27xk3q';
echo "<pre>";
echo "
ALIAS: $alias
ROUND: ", intval($alias, 36) , "\n" ,
"AGAIN: ", base_convert(intval($alias, 36), 10, 36)
;
```

This used to work, and still does on my home Mac computer. The output is:

```
ALIAS: myalias
ROUND: 2147483647
**AGAIN: zik0zj**

ALIAS: 27xk3q
ROUND: 134255366
AGAIN: 27xk3q
```

But when I upload this to my Linux server, it echoes different things!

```
ALIAS: myalias
ROUND: 49962861028
**AGAIN: myalias**

ALIAS: 27xk3q
ROUND: 134255366
AGAIN: 27xk3q
```

As you see, the "`myalias`" string just prints as itself in the Linux version of PHP.

If this doesn't work or is wrong code, I need to know a foolproof way of checking whether a string is a valid base36 version of an integer or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you see, the "myalias" string just prints as itself in the Linux version of PHP.

And it is **correct behaviour**. You get another results on your mac - because it is 32bit and your number is truncated to `2147483647` (`2^32 - 1`)

```
if (preg_match('~^[a-z\d]+$~', $string)) {
    // valid base36
}
```

Comment: This looks like I'm in a soup. I have inherited a database where the previous programmer thought it was a good idea to use as a primary key in a table the base36 version of a sequence. He did not save the respective integers. 

The app is programmed in such a way that this column defaults to an automated string (base36 of the associated sequence), but users have the option to enter a customized string.  

I now need to distinguish which were automated integers converted into base36 string equivalents, and which were customized strings entered by users. 

Any ideas? Thx!

Comment: @PKHunter: well, I don't think it is even possible

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that one of your machines is working with a 32bit signed int (the first one), the other is working with 64bit signed ints (or possibly larger) on that `intval` conversion. [See the [`inval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) docs for ranges.]

`myalias` converted from Base36 exceed 0x7FFFFFFF (maximum signed 32bit value), while it's exact with a 64bit signed int (0xba204c1e4 == 49962861028). So the one you think is "broken" (the linux one), is actually the **correct** version. The first one is not working because of overflow.

Every string composed of `0-9a-z` chars is a valid Base36 number. The only checking you can do is checking that all the characters in the string are in the valid range, (and check for overflow (test if the value returned is the maximum int) - unreliable).

Comment: you mean 0-9a-z instead of 1-9a-z